# Why is my state variables being rendered twice in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Every time I use react and the useEffect method my state variable renders twice. Once an empty variable and the next the desired variable. What can I try to help avoid this problem for now and in the future?

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";

export default function Member (props) {

  const [team,setTeam] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let array = ["hello","hi"];
    setTeam(array);
  }, [])

  console.log(team);
  return (
    <>
     {team.forEach(i => <p>{i}</p>)}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi marcus, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use map to render an array in JSX:

```
export default function Member(props) {
  const [team, setTeam] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let array = ["hello", "hi"];
    setTeam(array);
  }, []);

  console.log(team);
  return (
    <>
      {team.map(i => ( // use map here
        <p>{i}</p>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

`forEach` doesn't return anything, so you can't use it to render components like that.

Also in your code instead of using `useEffect` to setup initial state, you can just set it straight in `useState`:

```
export default function Member(props) {
  const [team, setTeam] = useState(["hello", "hi"]);

  console.log(team);
  return (
    <>
      {team.map(i => ( // use map here
        <p>{i}</p>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an abvious behavior.

Component render's first time with initial state. After `useEffect` (componentDidMount) again re-renders.

So you are getting two `console.log`.

To avoid this, you need to set the state initally,

```
const [team,setTeam] = useState(["hello","hi"]);
```

and remove `useEffect`.

**Note:** `forEach` won't print data, you need `map` here,

```
{team.map(i => <p key={i}>{i}</p>)} //provide a key here
```